# Merging the class and dialog in vc++

Tags: visual-c++

I have a two systems to develop the vc++ mfc project. We working in single project. How do we merge the two different header files,cpp files,dialog developed in different systems. But the project(Projectname.dsw) is same. Instead of redesigning and rework. Can any one advise.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

If the files have the same names you can use another application like Git to do this merge. You commit the first project and after commit the another one and do the merges using the Git interface. I never did this but I think this gonna work. Winmerge can help to do this manually too, file by file.